# How to insert the same line in multiple rows in a YAML file at once

Tags: vim

Is there any way to insert the same line in multiple rows of a YAML file. For example the YAML:

```
fields:
    id:
        label: ID
        disabled: true
    full_name:
        label: Full Name
    shipping_address:
        label: Shipping Address
```

should become:

```
fields:
    id:
        label: ID
        disabled: true
        span: auto
    full_name:
        label: Full Name
        span: auto
    shipping_address:
        label: Shipping Address
        span: auto
```

Comment: See [Is there a way to paste at multiple locations/lines in vim?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/21836/is-there-a-way-to-paste-at-multiple-locations-lines-in-vim)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
:g/\v^(\s{4})\S+:/exe "norm! YpAfoo: bar\<esc>^df:>>>>"
```

- You should change the `{4}` to the right indentation, it depends on the new item goes under which level.
- This will insert the new entry in the **first** position.

With your example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Something almost perfect:

```
g/label:/ put='        span: auto'
```

The only problem happens on the ID block, or how to get the final line as a pattern to use in the global command.

Comment: That is not the "only" problem. What if some item doesn't contain key "label"? and if a key under some other level is called "label" too?